A closed convex set of constant width cannot contain a flat line segment in its boundary.
Given a closed and convex set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with constant width, we want to show that if a line segment $\overline{xy}$ is contained in $\partial A$, then $x$ and $y$ have to be the same point.  We suppose for contradiction that $\overline{xy} \in \partial S$ but $x \neq y$. Then we want to show that $A$ is not a set of constant width. We let $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ be two parallel lines of support of $A$ perpendicular to $\overline{xy}$. Then the distance between $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ is equal to $w_{1}$, which is the constant width of $A$. BUt Im not sure how to get a contradiction from the assumption that $\overline{xy} \in \partial A$.

Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2809902/42969

What does constant width mean?

@copper.hat It means the width of this set in every direction is the same.

$A= { (x,y) | x \ge 0 }$, then the entire $y$ axis is in $A$. Presumably you want a finite width.

First sandwich the shape between two lines, one through the line segment on the boundary and the other parallel and on the opposite side of the shape. Choose two distinct points on the line segment, call them $x$ and $x'$ both of which are on the same half of the segment. Then choose a point $y$ from the line opposite the segment.
Since $y$ is on a line parallel to and distinct from the line through $x$ and $x'$ the three points are not collinear. As they are both on the same half of the segment the triangle formed by $x,x'$ and $y$ cannot be isosceles. This implies that one of $x$ or $x'$ is closer to $y$, and therefore the set cannot be of constant width.
